# Does Google push out security updates for Android Kitkat?

Tags: android, security, ssl, android-4.4-kitkat

I am having ssl issues with my app on Android Kitkat. I noticed from doing a bit of research that Google doesn't push out security updates for Kitkat anymore. Is this true? If this is true where do I find the official documentation to prove this? I assume this is part of why later Android OS's don't seem to have this problem.

I am also trying to decide whether I should bother giving support for kitkat users on my app, if Kitkat doesn't get security patches should I really bother?

Here is the stacktrace if you are curious.

ssl issues

> 02-20 11:05:44.568 9596-11330/ javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x60281440: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
>   02-20 11:05:44.578 9596-11330/     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
>   02-20 11:05:44.578 9596-11330/     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:378)
>   02-20 11:05:44.578 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:267)
>   02-20 11:05:44.578 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:237)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:148)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:179)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:63)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at .services.myretrofit.new_api.Retro_LoginOAth.execute(Retro_LoginOAth.java:56)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at .fragments.Login$8.run(Login.java:280)
>   02-20 11:05:44.588 9596-11330/     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Answer (score 2):

It's vendor's job to provide security updates for their devices, so you have to check vendor's site for this.

For example, here's update plan for Google devices: https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/4457705#pixel_phones&nexus_devices

However, in many cases you can check if device has a security patch in runtime. May be this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed from doing a bit of research that Google doesn't push out security updates for Kitkat anymore. Is this true?

Presumably, though that is not your problem. Even when Google makes security patches available for older devices, manufacturers may not ship firmware updates containing those patches.

> If this is true where do I find the official documentation to prove this?

https://source.android.com/security/ contains information about AOSP security, including their security bulletins outlining discovered flaws and what Android versions they have patched (again, at the AOSP level).

> I am also trying to decide whether I should bother giving support for kitkat users on my app, if Kitkat doesn't get security patches should I really bother?

If your concern is client devices getting security patches, do not write client-side software.